# How to count the number of occurrences that a certain value occurs in a DataFrame according to another column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame that has two columns as such:

```
     item1    label
0      a        0
1      a        1
2      b        0
3      c        0
4      a        1
5      a        0
6      b        0
```

In sum, there are a total of three kinds of items in the column `item1`. Namely, `a`, `b`, and `c`. The values that the entries of the `label` column are either `0` or `1`.

What I want to do is receive a DataFrame where I have a count of how many entries in `item1` have `label` value `1`. Using the toy example above, the desired DataFrame would be something like:

```
     item1    label
0      a        2
1      b        0
2      c        0
```

How might I achieve something like that?

I've tried using the following line of code:

```
df[['item1', 'label']].groupby('item1').sum()['label']
```

but the result is a Pandas Series and also displays some behaviors and properties that aren't desired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can use [`pd.crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
count_1=pd.crosstab(df['item1'],df['label'])[1]
print(count_1)

item1
a    2
b    0
c    0
Name: 1, dtype: int64
```

---

To get a DataFrame:

```
count_1=pd.crosstab(df['item1'],df['label'])[1].rename('label').reset_index()
print(count_1)

  item1  label
0     a      2
1     b      0
2     c      0
```

---

**The good thing about this method is that it allows you to also get the number of 0 easily, which if you use the sum you don't get**

Answer (score 1):

Filter columns before `groupby` is not necessary, but you can specify column after `groupby` for aggregation `sum`. For 2 columns DataFrames add `as_index=False` parameter:

```
df = df.groupby('item1', as_index=False)['label'].sum()
```

Alternative is use [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html):

```
df = df.groupby('item1')['label'].sum().reset_index()
```

---

```
print (df)
  item1  label
0     a      2
1     b      0
2     c      0
```